# How to Get RAM size In windows metro?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I googling for a while but can't find an answer on a simple question.
Is it possible do get a device's amount of RAM from Metro style app using C#?
In windows phone 8.1 i can get just memoryLimit.

```
 var memoryLimit = Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit;
 memoryLimit = (memoryLimit / 1024) / 1024;
 Debug.WriteLine("Device Memory Limit: "+memoryLimit+"MB");
```

It's enough to determine is it 512MB RAM Device or Higher. How can i determine this In Windows 8.1 Apps?

Comment: There is no way to do this in Windows 8.1 Store apps

Comment: But is there any way to determine that device have a low amount of memory? <512mb or <1Gb?

Comment: I don't think they exist -- even [this $99 tablet](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/HP-Stream-7-Signature-Edition-Tablet/productID.308781500) has 1 Gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no way to do this in Windows 8.1 Store apps. And there are no devices with less, than 1Gb RAM